# Images & CSS not loading in iPhone UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, html, uiwebview

When my UIWebView loads my index.html the CSS and JavaScript references show as broken. What is wrong with the code below? (I verified that appUrlString is pointing to the correct directory)

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@""];
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile];

NSString *appUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/web/", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
NSURL *appUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:appUrlString];

[_appWebView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:appUrl];
```

This is what shows in the simulator.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

`NSURL *appUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:appUrlString];`

because it's a local filePath. In your version 'appURL' was giving back nil.
So no baseurl got set.